# How to initialize a final optional field in Scala?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, option-type

I am sorry if this was asked before, because this is something trivial, but I could not find an answer. How do I do this in Scala:

```
class Test{
    final Optional<WebView> webView;

    Test(boolean b){
        webView = b ? Optional.of(new WebView()) : Optional.absent();
    }
}
```

The goal of this excerpt, which uses Guava, is to initialize a non-reassignable optional field. One could do the same with using regular Java references and `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Test(b: Boolean) {
  val webView: Option[WebView] = if (b) Some(new WebView) else None
}
```

You *do* have to initialize a `val` in the same place it is declared, but you can use constructor arguments for it.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, that would look like this:

```
class Test(b: Boolean) {
  val webView: Option[WebView] = if (b) Some(new WebView()) else None
}
```